# How to attach bootstrap-colorpicker to my laravel/blade page?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, npm, laravel-blade

I installed 
https://github.com/farbelous/bootstrap-colorpicker
plugin to my laravel 5.7 / Bootstrap v4.1. / Jquery 3 / Blade application
and question is which is the correct way of attaching files I need to my page ?
I need this plugin only on some pages, so in this page I did :

```
    ...
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    ...
    <script src="{{ asset('js/'.$frontend_template_name.'/print_to_pdf_options.js') }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}"></script>
    <link href="../../node_modules/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../../node_modules/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
    ...
    <script>

@endsection
```

But this way does not work and seems invalid.
Which way is valid ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#stacks).

From the docs:

> Blade allows you to push to named stacks which can be rendered
>   somewhere else in another view or layout. This can be particularly
>   useful for specifying any JavaScript libraries required by your child
>   views:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/example.js"></script>
@endpush
```

In your Layout:

```
<head>
    <!-- Head Contents -->

    @stack('styles')
</head>
<body>

    @stack('scripts')
</body>
```

View where you need the plugin:

```
@push('styles')
    <link href="../../node_modules/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/'.$frontend_template_name.'/print_to_pdf_options.js') }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}"></script>
    <script src="../../node_modules/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
@endpush
```